# how to get value currently binded to textbox?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

i need your advice, please:)

I have a textbox inside a FlipView bound to title property, that shows current Title of a page.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="jmeno" FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
```

And i have a media element showing a video.

```
<MediaElement x:Name="mmedia" Source="Video/prvniVideo.mp4" Height="300"  Grid.Row="1" KeyUp="mmedia_KeyUp" />
```

I would like to open different video on different pages and I am trying to accomplish it like this - read the actual display value of texblock and base on that decide, which video to open in media element.

Something like this.

```
        string AktualniStranka;
        AktualniStranka = jmeno.Text;

        if (AktualniStranka == "Exercise 1")
        {
            mmedia.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Video/prvniVideo.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            mmedia.Play();
        }
        else
        {
            mmedia.Source = new Uri("ms-appx:/Video/Gumm.mp4", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            mmedia.Play();
        }
```

But it is not working - I have tried to read just the text of the textblock and put it in another textblock and it is not working either,  I have spent almost the whole day trying to make it work.. Please help guys:)

Full XAML code:

```
<common:LayoutAwarePage
x:Name="pageRoot"
x:Class="ContosoCookbook.ItemDetailPage"
DataContext="{Binding DefaultViewModel, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:ContosoCookbook"
xmlns:data="using:ContosoCookbook.Data"
xmlns:common="using:ContosoCookbook.Common"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d">

<Page.Resources>

    <!-- Collection of items displayed by this page -->
    <Style x:Name="transportStyle"  TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="40" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11" />
    </Style>

    <CollectionViewSource
        x:Name="itemsViewSource"
        Source="{Binding Items}"
        d:Source="{Binding AllGroups[0].Items, Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}"/>

    <common:ListConverter x:Key="ListConverter" />

    <Style x:Key="BragAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BragAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Brag"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE170;"/>
    </Style>

    <Style x:Key="ReminderAppBarButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource AppBarButtonStyle}">
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="ReminderAppBarButton"/>
        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Reminder"/>
        <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE121;"/>
    </Style>

    <local:ProductLicenseDataSource x:Key="License" />
    <common:BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>

</Page.Resources>

<Page.BottomAppBar>
    <AppBar x:Name="PageAppBar" Padding="10,0,10,0">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="50*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel x:Name="LeftCommands" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Button x:Name="BragButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource BragAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="OnBragButtonClicked" />
                <Button x:Name="PinRecipeButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource PinAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="OnPinRecipeButtonClicked" />
                <Button x:Name="ReminderButton" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Style="{StaticResource ReminderAppBarButtonStyle}" Click="OnReminderButtonClicked" />
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel x:Name="RightCommands" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </AppBar>
</Page.BottomAppBar>


<!--
    This grid acts as a root panel for the page that defines two rows:
    * Row 0 contains the back button and page title
    * Row 1 contains the rest of the page layout
-->
<Grid
    Style="{StaticResource LayoutRootStyle}"
    DataContext="{Binding Group}"
    d:DataContext="{Binding AllGroups[0], Source={d:DesignInstance Type=data:SampleDataSource, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}}">

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="140"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>


    <!--
        The remainder of the page is one large FlipView that displays details for
        one item at a time, allowing the user to flip through all items in the chosen
        group
    -->


    <FlipView
        x:Name="flipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        TabIndex="1"
        Grid.RowSpan="2"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">

        <FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="FlipViewItem">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,137,0,0"/>
            </Style>
        </FlipView.ItemContainerStyle>

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                        <!-- Three-column grid for item-detail layout -->
                        <Grid Margin="120,0,20,20">
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="600" />
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                <ColumnDefinition />
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="0">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="jmeno" FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />





                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Column="4">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="Description" Margin="0,0,0,16"/>




                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding ShortDesctiption}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Directions}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="{Binding IsLicensed, Source={StaticResource License}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}" />
                                        <Button Width="225" Height="120" Background="#30ffffff" Click="OnPurchaseProduct" Visibility="{Binding IsTrial, Source={StaticResource License}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}">
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormattedPrice, Source={StaticResource License}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>
                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>

                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <!-- Visual states reflect the app's view state inside the FlipView -->
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

                                <!-- Respect the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="400"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>

                                <!-- When snapped, the content is reformatted and scrolls vertically -->
                                <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="scrollViewer" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="image" Storyboard.TargetProperty="MaxHeight">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="160"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>

        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>
    <!-- MEDIA PANEL-->

    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Grid.Row="1" >
        <Border   BorderThickness="5" BorderBrush="White" Background="Black"   HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="165,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <ContentControl x:Name="VideoContainer" Height="300" KeyUp="VideoContainer_KeyUp"     >

                <MediaElement x:Name="mmedia" Source="Video/prvniVideo.mp4" Height="300"  Grid.Row="1" KeyUp="mmedia_KeyUp" />
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>

        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="140,20,0,0">
            <Button Name="btnPlay" Click="btnPlay_Click" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Play" />
            <Button Name="btnPause" Click="btnPause_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Pause" />
            <Button Name="btnStop" Click="btnStop_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Stop" />
            <Button Name="btnReverse" Click="btnReverse_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Rewind" />
            <Button Name="btnForward" Click="btnForward_Click"
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Forward" />
            <Button Name="btnVolumeUp" Click="btnVolumeUp_Click" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="-" />
            <Button Name="btnVolumeDown" Click="btnVolumeDown_Click" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="+" />
            <Button Name="btnMute" Click="btnMute_Click" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Mute" />
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnFullScreenToggle" Click="btnFullScreenToggle_Click" 
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Full Screen ON" Margin="290,0,0,0" Width="302" />

        <TextBlock x:Name="poser" FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="poser" TextWrapping="Wrap" />


    </StackPanel>


    <!-- FlipView used in portrait mode -->
    <FlipView
        x:Name="portraitFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,-3,20,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        Visibility="Collapsed">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                        <!-- Vertical StackPanel for item-detail layout -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="100,0,20,0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <Image x:Name="image" Width="400" Margin="0,20,0,40" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="Ingredients" Margin="0,0,0,16"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" LineHeight="32.5" Text="{Binding Ingredients, Converter={StaticResource ListConverter}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                            </StackPanel>

                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="Directions" Margin="0,24,0,16"/>
                                <ScrollViewer Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}">
                                    <Grid>
                                        <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Directions}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="{Binding IsLicensed, Source={StaticResource License}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}" />
                                        <Button Width="225" Height="120" Background="#30ffffff" Click="OnPurchaseProduct" Visibility="{Binding IsTrial, Source={StaticResource License}, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter }}">
                                            <Button.Content>
                                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding FormattedPrice, Source={StaticResource License}}" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" />
                                            </Button.Content>
                                        </Button>

                                    </Grid>
                                </ScrollViewer>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

    <FlipView
        x:Name="snappedFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemsFlipView"
        AutomationProperties.Name="Item Details"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Margin="0,-3,0,0"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}"
        Visibility="Collapsed">

        <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <UserControl Loaded="StartLayoutUpdates" Unloaded="StopLayoutUpdates">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="scrollViewer" Style="{StaticResource VerticalScrollViewerStyle}" Grid.Row="1">

                        <!-- Vertical StackPanel for item-detail layout -->
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="20,0,20,0">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Text="{Binding Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <Image x:Name="image" Width="260" Margin="0,12,0,40" Stretch="Uniform" Source="{Binding Image}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <TextBlock FontSize="20" FontWeight="Light" Text="Ingredients" Margin="0,0,0,16"/>
                                <TextBlock FontSize="16" FontWeight="Light" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Ingredients, Converter={StaticResource ListConverter}}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </UserControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
    </FlipView>

    <!-- Back button and page title -->
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button x:Name="backButton" Click="GoBack" IsEnabled="{Binding Frame.CanGoBack, ElementName=pageRoot}" Style="{StaticResource BackButtonStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="pageTitle" Text="{Binding Title}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Grid.Column="1" IsHitTestVisible="false"/>
        <Button Name="btnFullScreenOff" Click="btnFullScreenToggle_Click"   
        Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Full Screen OFF" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,56,495,36" RenderTransformOrigin="-9.161,0.266" Height="48" Width="106" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>

    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>

        <!-- Visual states reflect the application's view state -->
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="ApplicationViewStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenLandscape"/>
            <VisualState x:Name="Filled"/>

            <!-- The back button respects the narrower 100-pixel margin convention for portrait -->
            <VisualState x:Name="FullScreenPortrait">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource PortraitBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="flipView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="portraitFlipView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>

            <!-- The back button and title have different styles when snapped -->
            <VisualState x:Name="Snapped">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="backButton" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedBackButtonStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="pageTitle" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Style">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource SnappedPageHeaderTextStyle}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="flipView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="snappedFlipView" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Visible"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>

                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
</Grid>
```

Full C# code:

Comment: sorry about typos, I am just tired, so just to say sorry..

Comment: The context of when and how you are attempting to read the Text property will be necessary to solve your problem (e.g. the event handler). It would also be useful if you explained what you are observing when it fails to work, e.g. what is the debugger telling you, is the event handler being hit etc.). There is not enough information here.

Comment: Right we need to determine if the binding is the problem, or if it could be something else. Check your output and tell us what value yu see with debugger. Thks

Comment: I have tried to put event handler to many places, but cannot find the right place. The best what I could did so far is to tu put it inside the event handler of the last button on the page( my idea is that when this last button is renderred, the button to which I bound earlier should already have the proper value)

so I ma executting my code behind in the event that fires this button

    <Button x:Name="btnFullScreenToggle" Click="btnFullScreenToggle_Click" 
Style="{StaticResource transportStyle}" Content="Full Screen ON" Margin="290,0,0,0" Width="302" Loaded="btnFullScreenToggle_Loaded" />

Comment: Code behind for this button is:
    private void btnFullScreenToggle_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            /// funkce na zobrazeni menuVidea
            TextBlock jmeno = FindChildControl<TextBlock>(this, "jmeno") as TextBlock;
            StackPanel videoVyber = FindChildControl<StackPanel>(this, "videoVyber") as StackPanel;

            if (jmeno.Text == "Welcome")
            {
                videoVyber.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                videoVyber.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

Comment: This Textblock is binded to title of pages (three of them in each group of titles). The titles are Welcome, Overwie, Diagnosis.

With the code presented here it is able to read only the first title(Welcome) no metter which title is it actually displaying on the screen. So if user select the screen pages in one Group the textblock correctly shows appropriatte title, but in a code behind it only show the value of the first title.

Comment: Basicly what I want to do is - which content is currentlu user viewing and play appropriate video to it. So in Welcome page i want to play Welcome video, in Diagnosis page I want to play Diagnosis video. But so far for all titles in one group it only reads the Welcome (that is the first one in the row)

May be my questions can be reformulated - on which event of which control should i run my code behind to find out the actual value, that is displayed to the user?

Thank you guys>]

Answer (score 0):

What I see is that you are trying to get the value displayed, from the name of you Textblock (jmeno), right ?

You should not do that. Your textblock is defined in a datatemplate, the only reason to assign it a name is to apply a storyboard.

What you should do, is get your Flipview's SelectedItem object (which is your visual element datacontext), and get the Title property of that data object.

So :

(flipView.SelectedItem as -WhateverYourTypeIs-).Title, and there you should have your value.

Comment: That is exactly what I am trying to do:) and base od that value display appropriate video, which i believe code is working well:)

I am going to try your solutions, thank you in advance.

Comment: I am not sure if I get your solution right, please help me out. 

For the test purposes I created a Textblock to which I am truing to get the current value of "jmeno" textbox

<TextBlock x:Name="TestTextBlock" FontSize="26.667" FontWeight="Light" Text="Simple Text Before Changed" Margin="200,20,0,26" />

Comment: in code behind i use this function (is it what you have meant?)


private DependencyObject FindChildControl<T>(DependencyObject control, string ctrlName)
{
int childNumber = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(control);
for (int i = 0; i < childNumber; i++)
{
DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(control, i);
FrameworkElement fe = child as FrameworkElement;
if (fe == null) return null;
if (child is T && fe.Name == ctrlName)
{
}
else
{
DependencyObject nextLevel = FindChildControl<T>(child, ctrlName);
if (nextLevel != null)
return nextLevel;
}
}
return null;
}

Comment: finally to test it i use this

TextBlock Testjmeno = FindChildControl<TextBlock>(this, "jmeno") as TextBlock;
TestTextBlock.Text = Testjmeno.Text;

but it is still doind the same, it anly asigns the value "Overview" on all three pages of the group..

What I am doing wrong?